# Using cmpsb in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have been struggling to understand how `cmpsb` works in assembly, as I am trying to do a program that compares an input string which I supposedly saved in a variable with a string that is already defined in another variable, and if both are the same ones, it should print a 'y' and if not, it prints a 'n'. I used an example included in the emulator8086 to work my way out.

```
name "cmpsb"

org     100h

; set forward direction:
        cld     

;read from keyboard
mov dx, offset teclado
mov ah, 0ah
int 21h

; load source into ds:si,
; load target into es:di:
        mov     ax, cs
        mov     ds, ax
        mov     es, ax
        lea     si, teclado
        lea     di, str1

; set counter to string length:
        mov     cx, size

; compare until equal:
        repe    cmpsb
        jnz     not_equal

; "yes" - equal!
        mov     al, 'y'
        mov     ah, 0eh
        int     10h

        jmp     exit_here

not_equal:

; "no" - not equal!
        mov     al, 'n'
        mov     ah, 0eh
        int     10h

exit_here:

    ; wait for any key press:
    mov ah, 0
    int 16h

        ret

; strings must have equal lengths:
x1:
str1 db 'cadena'
teclado db 7,?,7 dup(" ")
size = ($ - x1) / 2
```

So far whenever I type 'cadena' in my input, it still doesn't recognize that both the input and the stored variable are the same, so it prints a 'n'. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: At first glance, your `size` is wrong.

Comment: that's what I'm not quite getting from assembly, how am I supposed to set a size of something that I haven't typed yet?, because in the original example this program compares two already set strings and uses that size formula.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Since your `cadena` is fixed here, you know its size. You should first check whether the length of the entered string is the same, and only compare if so.

Comment: But shouldn't be typing the same string enough to do that?

Comment: I just want to compare my input with a fixed variable known as 'cadena'

Comment: Yes, if the input has matching length then that would work. **If** you fixed the value of `size` ... your expression magic does not give the correct size. From a glance, it gives `10`, not `6`.

Comment: Despite that I already fixed the value of size to 6 to match the one that it's already stored, I still can't get the program to recognize that both are equal.

Comment: Yes, that's because of another issue, namely that your input string is not at `teclado`. Rather it is at `teclado+2` (due to the 2 byte header).

Answer (score 2):

Since you got the input through DOS function 0Ah the *source* will be at *[teclado + 2]*. If the user at the keyboard typed in a shorter (than 6 characters) string, results will not be what you expect. You have to check for this case.

```
; load source into ds:si
; load target into es:di
    mov     ax, cs  \
    mov     ds, ax   | Better move these 3 lines to the top of your program
    mov     es, ax  /
    lea     si, [teclado + 2]
    lea     di, str1

; set counter to string length:
    mov     cx, size

; compare enough characters
    cmp     [si-1], cl    ;[si-1] is where you had a ? in teclado
    jne     not_equal

; compare until equal:
    repe    cmpsb
    jnz     not_equal
```

The calculation of *size* should not encompass *teclado*. Just move it up a line.

```
str1 db 'cadena'
size = ($ - str1)
teclado db 7,?,7 dup(" ")
```